# OpenLayers 3.6.0 - getting error when trying to use WebGL renderer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the webgl renderer - "Uncaught TypeError: rq[c] is not a function ol.js:408"

```
map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: interactions,
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                preload: Infinity,
                source: source
            }),
            vectorLayer
        ],
        renderer: 'webgl',
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: proj,
            center: [5841, -1347],
            zoom: 5,
            minZoom:5 ,
            maxZoom: 6,
            extent: [0, -imgHeight, imgWidth, 0],

        })
    });
```

Everything works fine when I switch 'renderer: 'webgl' to renderer: 'canvas'.

I'm testing in Chrome (up to date) and using [this](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/brightness-contrast.js) as reference

Answer (score 3):

Only the canvas renderer supports vector data. The docs for the renderer option contains "*Note that at present only the Canvas renderer supports vector data*". http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html

If you really want vector data with the webgl renderer, consider using [ol.source.ImageVector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageVector.html).